# C extension not working in Python 3.7 says ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_loop)

Tags: c, python-3.x, virtualenv, importerror

I have created a C extension to create a loop and print 10 objects. It is compiling successfully but when I import it in python program and compile it then the terminal gives me an error saying:

**ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_loop)**

Using ubuntu 19.04 with Python 3.7. I have created a virtualenv and I am doing whole work in it. Couldn't find specific solution anywhere but I someone said that the C file is hooking up with the Python2.7 in my system but since I am using virtualenv I don't expect this to be the case. Doing it for the first time.

This is my C Extension File

```c
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static PyObject* loop(PyObject* self)
{
    int i =0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("The number is %d\n",i);
    }
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static char loop_docs[] = "loop(): This function is going to create a printing loop for 10 times.\n";

static PyMethodDef loop_methods[] = {
    {"loop", (PyCFunction)loop, METH_NOARGS, loop_docs},
    {NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef loop_module_def = 
{
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "loop",
    "Module that is still in development",
    -1,
    loop_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_fibonacci(void){
    Py_Initialize();

    return PyModule_Create(&loop_module_def);
}
```

this is my setup.py

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name='loop', version='1.0',ext_modules=[Extension('loop', ['loop.c'])])
```

this is the file I am trying to run

```py
import loop #<- Here Error Occurs

print(loop.loop())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The entry point of your native module (function with `PyMODINIT_FUNC`) should have a name based on the module name.
Here, this function is named `PyInit_fibonacci()` but your module is named `loop`.
I would suggest to name your function `PyInit_loop()` (or alternatively name your module `fibonacci`).

(https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html#c.PyInit_modulename)

Note that the error message shows the expected name for the missing function:

> ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_loop)

Answer (score 0):

In my case a fortran file was compiled with `f2py` under Python 3.6 providing `*.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.
Later running under Python 3.9 I obtained the error.

Compiling additionally with `python3.9 -m numpy.f2py -c -m ...` provided
`*.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and solved the error.